# Interpreting/Designing an AST or using an IR

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently implementing my own simple toy programming language. I would like this to be implemented as quickly as possible, but I am quite unsure where to go from the current stage I am in. I plan to make my language interpreted, as it seems that making an interpreter is *easier?* or *faster?* than making a compiler.

Anyhow, I am quite in a pickle, I have created my parser/lexer with Bison/Flex, however I have not made my AST. The reason for this, is because I was planning to interpret the AST, however I'm quite unsure how I would design the AST that benefits from polymorphism (I am using C++ as my implementation language) so I do not have to use a switch/if-else statements. Does anyone have any idea on how I should tackle this? Or should I not interpret an AST, and just compile to an IR and interpret the IR.

If that case is the latter, instead of inventing my own IR, what possible IRs and VMs (to interpret the IR) are there free to use without any limitations in my source code? I know of LLVM, but are there any others that I should possibly consider?

**EDIT:**

The programming language that I am creating is a simple C-like language and has some visual basic traits thrown in there. It is statically typed, with two avaliable primitives: a number (floating point) or a string of text.

Here is what it looks like:

```
begin // start of the program

   num x = 3;                // make a number
   str text = "Hello World"; // make a string

   print text + x; // prints out "Hello World3"

end // end of the program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a first attempt, interpreting an AST using polymorphic member functions is fine. Of course, it will be quite slow for several reasons and you'll have to switch to a completely different approach to significantly improve performance, but a working but slow program is better than a broken but potentially fast program. That would look a bit like this, ignoring the problem of representing several types:

```
struct Node { virtual int eval(); };
struct Const : Node {
    int n;
    virtual int eval() { return n; }
};
struct Add : Node {
    Node *lhs, *rhs;
    virtual int eval() { return lhs->eval() + rhs->eval(); }
};
```

Creating your own IR is more work: Now you have to specify two languages, and still implement one. Using an existing IR doesn't have these problems and *can* be simpler, but you still have to compile to that IR. This step is quite hard if the IR isn't a good fit for your language, and you have to deal with all the complexity and idiosyncrasies the IR may have. Without knowing your language, it's impossible to recommend anything.

Edit: Your language looks simple enough to be compiled straight to LLVM, though it may take you a while to understand LLVM IR well enough to do the translation. You'll also have to pin down some implementation details (e.g. allocation of strings) that a C++ interpreter could delegate to the standard library (e.g. `std::string`). Other major VMs such as the JVM and the CLR operate at a higher level and support strings directly, but I'd wager their tools for generating IR are inferior to LLVM's C++ API and they mandate some additional boilerplate (e.g. putting everything into a class). Plus, then you're dependent on that VM.

I'd still suggest you first implement an AST-directed interpreter, though I may be partial as that's how I started out.

Comment: I just added a basic snippet/explanation in my main post of what my programming language looks like.